# How to most correctly work with Interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net

Is this code correct as a pattern? Which way is better, like this or via Parent class Message.

Or is it better to use only 3 classes and 1 Interface? Where I type something like:

**INotification Notify = new SystemMessage();**

```
public interface INotification { void ShowNotification(String text); }


    class Message : INotification
    {
        static internal Message CurrentMessageType { get; set; }
        public virtual void ShowNotification(string text) {
            if (CurrentMessageType == null) CurrentMessageType = new SystemMessage();
        }
    }

    class SystemMessage : Message {
        public override void ShowNotification(string text) {
            Console.WriteLine("SYSTEM: " + text);
        }
    }

    class ConsoleMessage : Message {
        public override void ShowNotification(string text) {
            Console.WriteLine("CONSOLE: " + text);
        }
    }

    class NotifyMessage : Message {
        public override void ShowNotification(string text) {
            Console.WriteLine("NOTIFY: " + text);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.Write("MSG: ");
                String rsp = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (rsp)
                {
                    case "sys":
                        Message.CurrentMessageType = new SystemMessage();
                        break;
                    case "con":
                        Message.CurrentMessageType = new ConsoleMessage();
                        break;
                    case "not":
                        Message.CurrentMessageType = new NotifyMessage();
                        break;
                    case "exit":
                        return;
                }

                Message.CurrentMessageType.ShowNotification("test message");

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you need that interface `INotification` at all. Rather you have a class hierarchy or inheritance relationship here and in such case having `Message` as your abstract base class would probably suffice all

```
public abstract class Message
{
    static internal Message CurrentMessageType { get; set; }
    public virtual void ShowNotification(string text) {
        if (CurrentMessageType == null) 
               CurrentMessageType = new SystemMessage();
    }
}
```

Per your comment: am not here to argue what's better but you should go by OOP concept I believe. Thus you should use class hierarchy if there exists some relationship between your classes. If not, then using interface would be good and in that case you would say that all those classes provide a similar kind of functionality with different implementation may be but they may not be related.

Comment: Ok, Whats better use Parent-Child classes with virual method or use 3 classes SystemMessage / ConsoleMessage / NotifyMessage and 1 Interface?

Comment: @koschannel, see edit in answer if helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need many classes, if they all do pretty much the same thing? For such a simple case as this, a good pattern would be KISS :)

```
class Message
{
    static internal string CurrentMessageType { get; set; } = "SYSTEM"
    static void ShowNotification(string text) {
        Console.WriteLine(CurrentMessageType + ": " + text);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Write("MSG: ");
            String rsp = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (rsp)
            {
                case "sys":
                    Message.CurrentMessageType = "SYSTEM";
                    break;
                case "con":
                    Message.CurrentMessageType = "CONSOLE";
                    break;
                case "not":
                    Message.CurrentMessageType = "NOTIFY";
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    return;
            }

            Message.ShowNotification("test message");

        }
    }
}
```